# :compileKotlin fails in Gradle (mixed Java + Kotlin project)

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I have a mixed Java/Kotlin project with the following structures:

My Gradle script for building it looks like this:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "com.mycopany.App"

sourceSets {
  deploy
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  testCompile  'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}

test.testClassesDir = project.tasks.compileTestKotlin.destinationDir

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion="2.7"
}
```

`App.kt` is a simple program:

```
package com.mycompany.App

class App {
    fun run() {
        System.out.println("Hello, Kotlin world!")
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val app = App()
    app.run()
}
```

When I try to build it using `gradle build`, I get the following error messages:

`16:13:16.768 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':copyMainKotlinClasses'
16:13:16.768 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :copyMainKotlinClasses FAILED
16:13:16.769 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :copyMainKotlinClasses (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.042 secs.
16:13:16.770 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.28 secs, idle: 0.005 secs
16:13:16.827 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
16:13:16.828 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
16:13:16.829 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]`

I get the same error, when I try to build it in Eclipse (also with Gradle).

If I run the same script with the `--stacktrace` option, I get this:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:265)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.OutputFilePropertyAnnotat
ionHandler$2$1.execute(OutputFilePropertyAnnotationHandler.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.OutputFilePropertyAnnotat
ionHandler$2$1.execute(OutputFilePropertyAnnotationHandler.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:621)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(Abstra
ctTask.java:604)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.ex
ecuteActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 57 more`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a typo in your main class name, and the actual main class generated by Kotlin is in fact `com.mycompany.AppKt`. Try fixing that, and see if it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the class name problem, but the build still doesn't work (still `:copyMainKotlinClasses` failure).

Comment: Can you please try with the latest version of Gradle?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Thanks. Setting `gradleVersion="3.1"` actually helped.